# How should i display data from 2 tables in 1 Repeater control in asp.net?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, data-binding, webforms, asprepeater

I can join 2 tables in SQL and it shows the result i want but in the code it returns that `tourName` column doesn't exist.

(`rezervation` table has `tourId` as foreign key)

```
SELECT      r.*, t.name as tourName    
FROM       [dbo].[rezervation] r(NOLOCK)    
inner join rezervationDetail rd(nolock) on r.ID = rd.rezervationId   
inner join tour t(nolock) on t.Id = rd.tourId
```

I call this SQL query as a stored procedure and it doesn't work. What should i do ?

Here is my View:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptReser" runat="server" OnItemCommand="rptReser_ItemCommand">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table width="100%" id="sample_2" />
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>No </th>
                <th>İsim </th>
                <th>Soyad </th>
                <th>Tur Adı </th>
                <th>Mail  </th>
                <th>Telefon </th>
                <th>Tarih </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </tbody>
        </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ID") %>  
            </td>
            <td>
                <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "name") %> 
            </td>
            <td>
                <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "surname") %> 
            </td>
            <td>
                <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "tourName") %> 
            </td>
            <td>
                <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "mail") %> 
            </td>
            <td>
                <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "phone") %> 
            </td>
            <td>
                <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "createDate", "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}") %> 
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: The `Repeater` knows nothing about what's happening inside the stored procedure. Since all data come out as one table result it's business as usual. Nevertheless, if there's something wrong with the data binding you need to include the **important** things in your example, i.e. the code you're using to bind the data to the `Repeater` in order to let us help you.

Comment: this code in BindRepeater List<rezervation> rezervations = rezervationManager.GetAllrezervations(prms);

Comment: and that method which i use for call store procedure         public static List<rezervation> GetAllrezervations(Dictionary<string, string> _params)
        {
            SqlParameter[] sqlParams = utility.util.ListToSqlParameter(_params);

            return dbEntityManager.GetObjectsByCriteria<rezervation>(GetAllProcedureName, sqlParams);
        }

Comment: Also i was using the same store procedure i just added some joins to other tables as you see but like i said i couldn't get those tables datas in my page